# c++ file will not run but does compile

Tags: c++

The file below will compile but not run, any advice?

The cursor will blink a couple of times then, stop. Don't know what the problem is?

run 1e7 samples for particles leaving the slab block. The idea is to take the average number of particles leaving the slab in the x direction.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int i , J;
    int numhistories = 1E7;
    int num_batch = 1E3;
    char * num_abs;

    double  N1 = 0.25;
    double Smallsigma1 = 2.0;
    double N2 = 0.75;
    double Smallsigma2 = 0.5; 
    double Tsigma = (N1 * Smallsigma1) + (N2 * Smallsigma2);
    double xmin = 0.0; // Slab geometry 
    double xmax = 5.0; // Slab geometry 


    double x, c , phi;
    double  count = 0, total_num_abs = 0; 
    num_abs =  (char*) malloc (J+1); 
    if (num_abs==NULL) exit (1); 

    for (J = 0; J < num_batch; J++)
        {
            count = 0; 

            for (i = 1 ; i < numhistories ; i++)
                {
                    // randomly intialize the x location of a neutron 
                    x = xmax * (float)rand() / (float)(RAND_MAX) ;
                    // first interaction 
                    c = 2 * (float)rand() - 1 ; 
                    phi = (float)rand() / (float)RAND_MAX; 
                    x += -log(phi) * c / Tsigma;
                    while ((x < xmax) && (x > xmin)) 
                        {
                            phi = (float)rand() /(float)RAND_MAX; 
                            if (phi < 1 / Tsigma)
                                {
                                    count += 1 ; 
                                    break; 
                                }
                            c = 2 * (float)rand() - 1 ; 
                            phi = (float)rand() /(float)RAND_MAX; 
                            x += (-log(phi)) * c / Tsigma;
                        }
                }
            num_abs[J] = count;
            total_num_abs += num_abs[J];         
        }
    double mean = (double)total_num_abs / (double)(numhistories * num_batch);
    count = 0; 
    for (J = 0; J < num_batch; J++)
        {
            count += (num_abs[J] - numhistories * mean) * (num_abs[J] - numhistories *mean);
        }
    double variance = (double)count / (double)(num_batch * num_batch);

    printf("mean = %f, variance = %f\n", mean , variance);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try running it in a debugger to see what is happening.

Comment: If all code that compiles, would run successfully, our jobs would **a lot** easier.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Not really.  You can often do this with template metaprogramming (solving the problem at compile time!), but it really isn't an easier way to do it.  ;)

Comment: Maybe the problem is the window closes after the program finishes.

Comment: @Yakk Well.. Template metaprogramming was never my strongest field (and I didn't do any work with that), so I was just talking from my point of view :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Does this need to be tagged as `c++` instead of `c`? Looks like  `c` to me.

Comment: And, to the OP, are you programming with C++, or C? Since I don't see any C++ in the code that you pasted (apart from `<iostream>` include, which you don't use).

Comment: @drescherjm [tag:c] like code compiled with a [tag:c++] compiler qualifies as [tag:c++].  The above code is clearly not legal [tag:c], it `#include <iostream>`, as well.

Comment: In addition, what is value of `J`, when `num_abs =  (char*) malloc (J+1); ` is run? Turn up all your warnings, they are not just suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't hit the print near the end of the program, and it doesn't seem to crash. Ergo it exits before. If you hook up a debugger and step through it, I'd suspect it end up exiting here:

```
num_abs =  (char*) malloc (J+1);
if (num_abs==NULL) exit (1);
```

J seems to be uninitialized and can therefore be any value. And as suggested in the comments, please fire up your warning-level to -Wall or something like that. Warnings are there to help you prevent these type of problems.

If for some reason there is no debugger available, you can stick in a few more prints here in there to narrow down the location of the problem.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! it was that and one of the unnecessary for loops.

Comment: Excellent. Glad you found it. If all is good, please accept my answer ;)